# Разные значения элемента массива в двойных кавычках и без

Tags: windows, powershell

Задача следующая: поиск внешних носителей, затем поиск определенных данных на них.
Определяю массив носителей

```
$removable_drives = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "drivetype=2"
```

Проверяю заполнение массива

```
PS C:\>  $removable_drives

DeviceID     : F:
DriveType    : 2
ProviderName :
FreeSpace    : 40318910464
Size         : 64252407808
VolumeName   : Transcend

DeviceID     : G:
DriveType    : 2
ProviderName :
FreeSpace    : 15007612928
Size         : 16044294144
VolumeName   : Transcend
```

Выбор значения буквы диска (в качестве примера - первый элемент массива)

```
PS C:\> $removable_drives[0].Name

F:
```

А если взять $removable_drives[0].Name в двойные кавычки (чтобы задавать определенных путь, например "$removable_drives[0].Name\docs"), то получаю следующее:

```
PS C:\> "$removable_drives[0].Name"

\\Имя_компьютера\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="F:" \\Имя_компьютера\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="G:"[0].Name
```

Насколько я помню, двойные кавычки в Powershell позволяют использовать внутри переменную, но почему она меняется, понять не могу.

Answer (score 1):

В строке

> `"$removable_drives[0].Name"`

powershell по умолчанию выполняет подстановку объекта по его названию (`$removable_drives`), а все, что написано дальше, воспринимает как элемент строки, а не как указание взять свойство `Name` элемента массива.
Необходимо следующее исправление:

```
"$($removable_drives[0].name)"
```